# Variable not updating in score tracking system for ios app

Tags: ios, swift

I programmed a variable to track scores in a mini-game but it is not reflecting the updated value after some code is executed.

I'm making a basic quiz mini-game which is embedded in an iOS app. It operates in an independent view controller and does not interface with any other section of the app. My code is giving no errors, but when I try to set a UILabel to the variable's value it reflects no change...

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgItemImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblItemName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblScore: UILabel!


@IBAction func btnRedBin(_ sender: Any) {
    trackScore(binChoice: "red")
}

@IBAction func btnYellowBin(_ sender: Any) {
    trackScore(binChoice: "yellow")
}

@IBAction func btnGreenBin(_ sender: Any) {
    trackScore(binChoice: "green")
}


var trashList:[String] = ["Can", "Brick", "Sandwich"]
var itemChoice:Int = 0
var score:Int = 0
var gameRound:Int = 0

func itemChange() {
    if gameRound <= 3 {
        itemChoice = Int.random(in: 0...((trashList.count)-1))
        lblItemName.text = trashList[itemChoice]
        imgItemImage.image = UIImage(named: (trashList[itemChoice]))
    } else {
        lblItemName.text = "You scored \(score) points!"
    }
    gameRound += 1
    lblScore.text = "\(score)"
}

func trackScore(binChoice:String){
    switch trashList{
    case ["Can"]:
        if binChoice == "red"{
            score = score - 1
        } else if binChoice == "yellow" {
            score = score + 10
        } else {
            score = score - 5
        }

    case ["Brick"]:
        if binChoice == "red"{
            score = score + 10
        } else if binChoice == "yellow" {
            score = score - 1
        } else {
            score = score - 5
        }

    case ["Sandwich"]:
        if binChoice == "red"{
            score = score + 10
        } else if binChoice == "yellow" {
            score = score - 1
        } else {
            score = score - 5
        }
    default:
        break
    }
    trashList.remove(at: itemChoice)
    itemChange()
}
```

I expect the variable "score" to change when one of the buttons (actions) is pressed. But when I do so and try to check by setting a UILabel "lblScore" to its value I always get 0.

Comment: Have you used breakpoints and debugging to check if the button action functions are being triggered? Are you seeing the `score` variable update? Have you checked that you're reaching the `lblScore.text = "\(score)"` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `trackScore()` you are `switch`-ing on `trashList`, but it often contains multiple items, so it won't match your cases.

Instead, you want:

```
func trackScore(binChoice:String){
    switch trashList[itemChoice] {
    case "Can":
        if binChoice == "red"{
            score = score - 1
        } else if binChoice == "yellow" {
            score = score + 10
        } else {
            score = score - 5
        }

    case "Brick":
        if binChoice == "red"{
            score = score + 10
        } else if binChoice == "yellow" {
            score = score - 1
        } else {
            score = score - 5
        }

    case "Sandwich":
        if binChoice == "red"{
            score = score + 10
        } else if binChoice == "yellow" {
            score = score - 1
        } else {
            score = score - 5
        }
    default:
        break
    }
    trashList.remove(at: itemChoice)
    itemChange()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how your trackScore function should look like

```
func trackScore(binChoice:String){
    switch binChoice:String{
    case "Can":
        if binChoice == "red"{
            score = score - 1
        } else if binChoice == "yellow" {
            score = score + 10
        } else {
            score = score - 5
        }

    case "Brick":
        if binChoice == "red"{
            score = score + 10
        } else if binChoice == "yellow" {
            score = score - 1
        } else {
            score = score - 5
        }

    case "Sandwich":
        if binChoice == "red"{
            score = score + 10
        } else if binChoice == "yellow" {
            score = score - 1
        } else {
            score = score - 5
        }
    default:
        break
    }
    trashList.remove(at: itemChoice)
    itemChange()
}
```